# Intellij play2 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/TrackLevel

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I get the below error while running 'sbt' command from the project created using 
Intellij 2017.3,
JDK 1.8.0_131,
Scala 2.12,
Play 2 FW 2.6.11

Step 1:Create a Play 2 project in Intellij Idea File -> New -> Project -> scala -> Play 2.x -> select the version of JDK, scala and Play show above.

Step 2: Run 'Play2Run' command
 or 
run  'sbt' command in terminal from project directory.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/TrackLevel
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at sbt.ModuleUtilities$.getObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:13)
at sbt.ModuleUtilities$.getCheckedObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:19)
at sbt.ModuleUtilities$$anonfun$getCheckedObjects$1.apply(ModuleUtilities.scala:22)
at sbt.ModuleUtilities$$anonfun$getCheckedObjects$1.apply(ModuleUtilities.scala:22)
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Updated the description with execution steps

Comment: Can't reproduce this with given steps. Can you try on another device?

Comment: This issue in not reproducible in another Mac machine. It looks to be machine issue. Thanks for looking into this issue.